# c++ error c2373 redefinition different type modifiers

Tags: c++, file, compiler-errors

When I run my program, I get this error.

> c++ error c2373 'readBalance' redefinition different type modifiers

I want to read what is in the file then write.

```
// ReadAndWrite.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

double readBalance;
double balance;

int main ()
{
    double readBalance();
    double balance = 0;
    ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open("renatofile.txt");
    char output [100];

    if (readfile.is_open())
    {
         while(!readfile.eof())
         {
             readfile>>output;
         }
    }
    readfile.close();
    balance=atof(output);
    return balance;
}
```

Can it be because I'm returning balance?

Comment: What do you think this line does: `double readBalance();`?? And how can you **run** a program, that doesn't compile?

Comment: because before nothing was showing, when i add double readBalance(); it showed what was in the text file. But now i get error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing what you wanted to do was to define readBalance as a function and then call it from main, something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>       // you need this for atof

using namespace std;

double readBalance();    // this is a function prototype
double balance;          // this is a global variable - you don't need this at all

int main ()
{
    cout << readBalance() << endl;    // this will print the balance 
    return 0;
}

double readBalance()
{
    double balance = 0;               // this local variable hides the global...
    ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open("renatofile.txt");
    char output [100];

    if (readfile.is_open()) {
        while(!readfile.eof()) {
            readfile>>output;
        }
    }
    readfile.close();
    balance=atof(output);
    return balance;
}
```

Note that you've declared `balance` both globally and locally and that's probably not what you want.

Btw, you're also missing the include needed for the `atof` function (cstdlib).

Comment: Doesn't show me what is the text file, does it work for you?

Comment: @RenatoAlberto I created a 'renatofile.txt' with only a number in, and the program showed that number as it's output, so yes, it did work for me.

Comment: something must be wrong, in the folders then.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of

```
    double readBalance();
```

I don't know why you put that there.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations placed in local scope still declare names with *external linkage*, not local names. This means that your local `double readBalance();` declaration declares `readBalance` as name of a *global function*. At the same time, a few lines above you declared `readBalance` as a *global variable*.

Since both entities are *global* (i.e. have external linkage), they conflict with each other. This conflict is what triggers the error message.

You might note that `balance`is also "redeclared" in local scope. With `balance` the conflict does not occur, since in local scope `balance` is declared as a *variable*. Variable declarations placed in local scope produce local names with no linkage. Thus, local variable `balance` is completely independent from the global variable `balance` declared above. This is perfectly legal.

So, the question is why are you attempting to declare `readBalance` as a variable and as a function at the same time? And what is `readBalance` supposed to be (since you never use it in your code)?